# ArcGIS Server migration across Operating Systems

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, linux, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to move an ArcGIS Server instance running on Linux with services to a Windows Server 2012 r2 env?  I've tried the recomended backup and recovery tool and unsurprisingly I get the below error when I try to restore on the windows machine:

`Import site failed with the following error. Import operation does not support creating a restore point on Linux and importing it on Windows.The restore of the site "localhost" failed.`

It does not seem like there is even a manual way to do this which is surprising since ArcGIS server is running with wine.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the version of software in use, though the error message does appear to be quite clear, making it more a matter to take up with Esri Tech Support.

Comment: The error is spit out after using the backup.py to generate the *. agssite on the Linux instance and running the the restore script on the windows instance.

Comment: You should probably specify that you want a solution other than the backup tool.  An indication of the number of services, and the types of those services might be of use as well.

Comment: Read that last sentence in the question. That's implied..the tag has all of the version info your comments add nothing to the discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESRI says: "Can't be done, the differences between the two systems is to great"

Source is esri tech support...I'm sure with enough scrapping and parsing you could get it to work.

Comment: Well that is an ugly situation.

Comment: Could you please site a source for this, or move this to the comment section?